# Ambient Context Where Members Have Dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ambientcontext

Hi this is probably just a lack of thought but I can't see how to solve this one "nicely". I have a component responsible for auditing that is used across the system, such:

```
public class RemoteAuditLogger: AuditLogger{}
```

where `AuditLogger` is an interface. As it stands I'm making use of constructor injection across several classes (this list of classes is growing). So I'm looking at implementing *Ambient Context*. The problem I have is that `RemoteAuditLogger` has dependencies of its own (in this case the remote audit service proxy).

So I want:

```
public abstract class SomeContext{
    private static SomeContext _currentCtx;
    public static SomeContext Current{
        get{
           if(_currentCtx == null){
              _currentCtx = new DefaultContext();
           }
           return _currentCtx;
        }
        set{
           _currentCtx = value;
        }
    }

    public abstract AuditLogger AuditLogger{ get; }
}
```

In this scenario `DefaultContext` will return a `RemoteAuditLogger`. Is there a way I  can retain the decoupled nature of the context whilst satisfying the dependencies of `RemoteLogger`? I don't want `SomeContext` depending on the remote audit proxy, for e.g., so it "feels" like I need to keep a default constructor on `DefaultContext`.

Comment: Is it MEF (or an handmade Reflection/Activator solution) an option?

Comment: Its using Autofac, if that helps.

Comment: Don't go that way. Auditing is a cross-cutting concern, so should be a Decorator or Interceptor, not a Strategy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7906547/126014

Comment: Here's another example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1709048/126014